# Select one row from each group using Core Data and MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data

In my database I store the chat record of current user and his friends. Say, my message entity is like:

> ownerId
>
> friendId
>
> text
>
> createdAt

I want to query the database (Core Data) groupping by friendId and select the last created message from each group.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this?

In particular, I am using MagicalRecord, so it will be good if you can show me how to do with it.

---

Update:

I realised I should use SQL like this:

```
select * from (select * from messages order by createdAt desc) temp group by friendId order by 'createdAt' desc;
```

But how to convert it into Core Data syntax?

Comment: @flexaddicted, I haven't tried because I am not sure where to start.

Comment: http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/ios-core-data-group-by-and-count-results/

Comment: @flexaddicted, thanks. But I do not want to count, but select the last row in each group...